# How to ignore a failure of an 'ExecStart' in Systemd

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, ubuntu-18.04, systemctl

I'm trying to create a service which runs several scripts using `ExecStart` and some of them can be failed. I need to ignore these failed scripts and return a success for the service.

Previously I used `upstart` and this is how I achieved it.

```
start on runlevel [23]
stop on shutdown

script
    set +e # Disable exit on non 0
    stop sys_process_script
    start sys_init_script
    start sys_process_script
    set -e # Enable exit on non 0
end script
```

But I don't know how to ignore the failed script. This is my implementation so far.

```
[Unit]
Description=System starter

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl stop sys_process_script
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl start sys_init_script
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl start sys_process_script
```

Is there any method to ignore the script if failed in `systemctl` or in `.service - onFailure`?

Comment: Note that if you're using `systemd` to call `systemctl` inside a service, you're doing something wrong :-) Look up the manuals on [Target Unit Configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html#), which explains how to group a series of `systemd` commands together in an unified way.

Answer (score 4):

I know this was asked quite a while ago, but `systemd` has a much simpler feature to ignore failed scripts.

Just prefix the path with a minus sign: `-`

e.g.

```
ExecStart=-/bin/systemctl stop sys_process_script
ExecStart=-/bin/systemctl start sys_init_script
ExecStart=-/bin/systemctl start sys_process_script
```

See an answer by [@mark-stosberg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20239/mark-stosberg) on [Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/348457/102206).

The reference is here: [Table 1. Special executable prefixes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=)

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to wrap inline

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c"command_which_will_fail; exit 0;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have that binary executable or script return an exit code of zero(0).